# how to calculate avrage of 1st 5 rows then next 5 row likewise continue in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, average

I have .xlsx file n rows and m column. I want to calculate average of 1st 5 rows then next 5 rows likewise ( each 5 interval average) continue for my data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Can you please provide some code or at least some sample data of your Excel spread sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your matrix, what about:

```
m=[];
for ii=1:5:20
m(end+1)=mean(mean(A(ii:ii+4,:)));
end
```

does it work for you?

Comment: Note that this is going to be extremely slow since you're continuously expanding the length of `m`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "hack" that should be pretty fast if A is big:

```
m = mean(kron(speye(size(A,1)/5),ones(1,5))*A/5,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reshape to get blocks of 5 rows in the first dimension. If `A` is your matrix

```
m = squeeze(mean(reshape(A,5,[],size(A,2)),1));
```

The code works as follows

1. reshape the matrix to get the blocks of 5 rows in the first dimension
2. Compute the mean over the blocks of 5 rows.
3. After the mean, the first dimension is a singleton so it is better to squeeze it so the output is a 2D matrix.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Could you consider accepting my answer then?